# Cloudfront: Forward host header to lambda function URL origin

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I have deployed the new [Lambda function URL](https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/using-amazon-cloudfront-with-aws-lambda-as-origin-to-accelerate-your-web-applications/) feature with a Cloudfront distribution to enable a custom domain. However, my backend needs the real host head and not the one Cloudfront rewrites (see host [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html#request-custom-headers-behavior)), in this case to the function URL https://xxxxxxxx.lambda-url.eu-central-1.on.aws/.

I also tried using the [managed origin request policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-managed-origin-request-policies.html) AllViewer, but this neither works and in the browser it returns: "Message: null" and the x-cache header says cloudfront error.

My config currently looks like this:

```
CloudFrontDistribution:
  Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
  Properties:
    DistributionConfig:
      PriceClass: PriceClass_100
      HttpVersion: http2
      IPV6Enabled: true
      Comment: Distribution for Lambda Function URL
      Origins:
        # extract function url form your lambda resource
      - DomainName: !Select [2, !Split ["/", !GetAtt ApiLambdaFunctionUrl.FunctionUrl]]
        Id: LambdaOrigin
        CustomOriginConfig:
          HTTPSPort: 443
          OriginProtocolPolicy: https-only
      Enabled: 'true'
      DefaultCacheBehavior:
        TargetOriginId: LambdaOrigin
        # Disable caching as http api did not allow either
        CachePolicyId: '4135ea2d-6df8-44a3-9df3-4b5a84be39ad'
        ViewerProtocolPolicy: redirect-to-https
        SmoothStreaming: 'false'
        Compress: 'true'
      Aliases:
        - sub.domain.com
      ViewerCertificate:
        SslSupportMethod: sni-only
        MinimumProtocolVersion: TLSv1.2_2019
        AcmCertificateArn: xxxxx
FunctionRecordSetGroup:
  Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup
  DeletionPolicy: Delete
  DependsOn:
    - CloudFrontDistribution
  Properties:
    HostedZoneName: domain.com.
    RecordSets:
      - Name: sub.domain.com
        Type: A
        AliasTarget:
          # The following HosteZoneId is always used for alias records pointing to CF.
          HostedZoneId: Z2FDTNDATAQYW2
          DNSName: { 'Fn::GetAtt': [CloudFrontDistribution, DomainName] }
```

How can I achieve forwarding the host header?

Comment: Did you try passing through the host header using the cache policy for the default behavior on the cloudfront distribution? Something like this: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/configure-cloudfront-to-forward-headers/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with CloudFront when parsing the `host` header via the `origin_request` and `origin_response` `Lambda@Edge` functions since the header contains the value of the `origin` because that is the request's destination. The request/response Lambdas are book-end functions that run before and after the call to the origin server.

In the case of [@peterhack](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73024633/8408636) (OP), the *Lambda function URL* ***is*** the `origin` without utilizing `Lambda@Edge` request/response interceptors, but the principle is the same.

A [CloudFront Function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/edge-functions.html#edge-functions-choosing) receives the correct host header because it receives the original `viewer_request` event. Since one cannot meaningfully overwrite the `host` header, I substituted a generic header `viewer-host` to receive the value:

```js
// Cloudfront Function (ES5)
// viewer_request
function handler(event) {
    var request = event.request;

    request.headers["viewer-host"] = request.headers.host;

    return request;
}
```

> **Note**: Here, we add the header to the `request` object and return the `request` object from the function so that CloudFront will continue onto the `origin` rather than immediately returning a `response`.

If you have trouble, AWS provides a [similar example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/example-function-add-cors-header-request.html) for modifying the request headers and includes links to more information.

Additionally, you will need to manually add the new header to the [Origin Request Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/controlling-origin-requests.html) since `AllViewer` cannot be used for a Lambda `origin` because it forwards the wrong header as indicated by [@carlos-garces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74003174/8408636) in this thread.

---

With the *Cloudfront Function* in place, modify your Lambda function to parse the new header.

`Lambda@Edge` example:

```js
const hostHeader = event.Records[0].cf.request.headers['viewer-host'][0].value
```

Lambda `origin` URL example:

```js
const hostHeader = event.headers['viewer-host']
```

---

One drawback is that your CloudFront Distribution will *always* run a CloudFront Function regardless of `origin` caching, and your desired origin Lambda will incur an additional Lambda invocation count, but only when reaching the `origin`.

With [2,000,000 free CloudFront Function invocations per month](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/pricing/), there is a buffer until incurring an added cost. Depending on your use case, it may fit within the free tier.

Comment: I see what you did there. Pretty sweet. Just use a CloudFront edge function to pass the host header along in another request header before it hits the Lambda function. Its SO strange that the CloudFront code does not do this. Puzzling really.

Comment: OK. I used this method to allow my origin Lambda to get access to the original domain name the viewer request in their browser. In addition I also added the "'viewer-host'" header to the default cache behavior to allow it to be used as part of the cache key. This will cause CloudFront to store different pages when a user request "example.com" or "www.example.com." Otherwise it will use the same cache for different host. Which is NOT what you want if you redirect "example.com" to "www.example.com." Causing a redirect loop depending on which host was hit was cached.

Answer (score 0):

The key is the **host** http header
You need to use " [https://xxxxxxxx.lambda-url.eu-central-1.on.aws/."](https://xxxxxxxx.lambda-url.eu-central-1.on.aws/.%22) as host header otherwise will not work.
Please check this anwser.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73364712