# AWS Cloudfront on Lambda Function via the Function URL url returning 403 Fobidden

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I have setup a lambda function url and cloudfront system

1. Lambda Function Url is straight forward, a function that will return an image or a json value
2. Cloudfront using this setting:

   - Origins:

     - Origin Domain: {LAMBDA FUNCTION URL}
     - Protocol: HTTPS only - TLSv1
     - Enable Origin Shield: No
   - Behavior:

     - Viewer: `Redirect HTTP to HTTPS`
     - Allowed HTTP Method: `GET, HEAD`
     - Restrict Viewer Access: `No`
     - Cache Policy: `Managed-CachingDisabled`
     - Origin request policy: `AllViewer`

The result however always return `403 Forbidden` with this body

```
{ "Message": null }
```

And this header

```
X-cache: Error from cloudfront
x-amzn-ErrorType: AccessDeniedException
```

Is there any setting that I missed that cause this error?
I already test direct hit using postman and browser to the function url an it works fine

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPDATE** - In your Origin Request Policy, set the new [AllViewerExceptHost](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-managed-origin-request-policies.html#managed-origin-request-policy-all-viewer-except-host-header) managed policy. That will forward all viewer headers except the `Host` header. Recommend you pair this with the `CachingDisabled` managed Cache Policy.

---

The issue could be that you are forwarding the `Host` header to your origin (Lambda Function URLs) via the *AllViewer* Origin Request Policy (ORP) that is attached to your cache behavior.

**Why does this happen?** You are using the *AllViewer* origin request policy, which forwards all HTTP request headers received from the viewer to your origin. So when CloudFront handles a request for `d123.cloudfront.net`—or even `example.com` as a configured CNAME—CloudFront will forward that value in the `Host` HTTP request header to your Lambda Function URLs origin. Because there is no function URL that resolves to that name, Lambda cannot find the function and returns a 403 Access Denied.

**How to resolve**: Instead of attaching the *AllViewer* origin request policy, create a custom origin request policy that forwards only the headers you need. Importantly, do not forward the `Host` header. Once this is configured, CloudFront will use your origin's hostname as the Host header—which Lambda will be able to resolve.

Comment: Thank you, it works so well, for my case, I also need to also forward `origin` and `user-agent` but it is because of my lambda function code.

Comment: Thank you for this questions + answer. I spent 3 days searching for a solution until I came across this article. I also had "AllViewer" policy. As soon as I updated to "AllViewerExceptHost" it worked immediately. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to apply a resource based policy on the lambda function to allow cloudfront to invoke it. Go to the lambda function --> configuration --> permissions --> Resource based policy. Add a new permission specifying the arn of the cloudfront distribution and the Action of "lambda:InvokeFunction". Hope this helps?